# Does RxJava2 Need Try/Catch on Create() Emitter?

Tags: rx-java2

Is this code:

```
Completable.create(emitter -> {     
    myDao().insert(data); // can throw exceptions
    emitter.onComplete();
});
```

The same as this code:

```
Completable.create(emitter -> {
    try {
        myDao().insert(data); // can throw exceptions
        emitter.onComplete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        emitter.onError(e);
    }
});
```

In other words: Do I have to surround my code with `try/catch` in order to propagate errors or will it be done automatically for me?

Comment: If your code inside is blocking/synchronous and won't throw a Throwable then no. Otherwise it is good to handle exceptions yourself so that you can use `tryOnError`.

Comment: So if I don't handle exceptions myself, will they be swallowed or will it be the same as `onError()` or will they crash the application with the error Plugin?

Comment: If your callback crashes, `create` will call `onError` for you, which may lead to `UndeliverableException`.

Comment: So the 2 codes I provided are the same...but using `tryOnError()` is cleaner?

Comment: See the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/completable/CompletableCreate.java#L40). Fatal errors are not signaled. Otherwise `tryOnError` saves you a lot of `UndeliverableException`s.

Comment: Got it, thank you, I appreciate a lot how you always come to help the community.